# Convex combinations and inner product.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Suppose we have non-zero vectors $u, w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a set of convexly independent non-zero vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Assume wlog that the $v_1, \ldots, v_m$ are indexed in such a way that
$$ 
u \cdot v_1 \geq u \cdot v_2 \geq \ldots u \cdot v_m
$$
and suppose it holds that whenever $u\cdot v_i \geq u \cdot v_j$, then also $w \cdot v_i \geq w \cdot v_j$, so that we can also write
$$ 
w \cdot v_1 \geq w \cdot v_2 \geq \ldots w \cdot v_m
$$

Now take any convex combination of the $v_i$, say
$$\sum_{i=1}^m c_i v_i$$
(note that each $c_i$ is between $0$ and $1$). I wanna show that if for an index $k$
$$ 
u \cdot \sum_{i=1}^m c_i v_i \geq u \cdot v_k
$$

then it also holds that
$$
w \cdot \sum_{i=1}^m c_i v_i \geq w \cdot v_k
$$
This doesn't have to be true so if you find a non-trivial counterexample it's also ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $m=n=3$ and take $v_1, v_2, v_3$ to be the basis vectors $e_1, e_2, e_3$ of $\mathbb R^3$. Then $u = (u_1, u_2, u_3)$ and $w = (w_1, w_2, w_3)$ just need to satisfy $u_1 \ge u_2 \ge u_3$ and $w_1 \ge w_2 \ge w_3$. Let's take $u = (3,2,1)$ and $w = (4,3,1)$.

Then $(\frac12, 0, \frac12)$ is a convex combination of $v_1, v_2, v_3$, so $\frac12 u_1 + \frac12 u_3 \ge u_2$ is a (true) inequality of the type we want to consider. However, $\frac12 w_1 + \frac12 w_3 \ge w_2$ is false: the left-hand side is $2.5$ and the right-hand side is $3$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Misha, do you think there is an additional assumption that would help make the statement hold in general?

Comment: would you rather I ask another question for this? @Misha Lavrov

Comment: I doubt that there is such an assumption that leaves a nontrivial statement to make.